# C#, Outline Interface-Attributes on implementing classes during design time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, attributes

Interfaces are no types, so when implementing them, their property attributes are not inherited. (which would be true of a base-class)

So, I'm currently wrapping my head around how to make this happen. Following example should pretty much explain what I mean, but unfortunately is not working as expected.

Reason is obvisously to centralize Instructions / Attributes without having to copy / paste them over and over.

```
public interface IPermissionBasedControl
 {
     [Browsable(true), Category("PermissionSystem"), Description("AccessKey required in order to use this control.")]
     String PermissionKey { get; set; }
 }

 public class ExtendedTextBox : TextBox, IReadOnlyControl, IDataBindable, IPermissionBasedControl
 {
    ...
    [AttributeProvider(typeof(IPermissionBasedControl))]
    public string PermissionKey { get; set; }
    ...
 }
```

Expectation: Visual Studio Designer will pick the `Category`, `Browsable` and `Description` Attribute from `IPermissionBasedControl` and display the property `PermissionKey` accordingly in the Designers Property-Window, when working with a `ExtendedTextBox`.

Actual result: Nothing happens, Default Category `Misc` is applied, no Description, Browsable default yes is applied.

- Is it not working, because Visual Studio Designer does not respect the `AttributProvider-Attribute`?
- Is it not working, because `AttributeProvider` cannot target an Interface?

I've also tried method access to no success:

```
 public class ExtendedTextBox : TextBox, IReadOnlyControl, IDataBindable, IPermissionBasedControl
 {
    ...
    [AttributeProvider(nameof(IPermissionBasedControl), nameof(IPermissionBasedControl.PermissionKey))]
    public string PermissionKey { get; set; }
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Imagine that you had an attribute with `AllowMultiple=false`. Then you create two interfaces, each of which define a property of the same name, and each puts this attribute on it. Then create a class which implements these two interfaces, with a single property. How would that work? If the attributes were transferred to the property, then you'd have inherited two instances of an attribute which has `AllowMultiple=false`

Comment: In that Case I would still have the choice, which Interfaces Attributes I reference with `AttributeProvider` (Or Do I missunderstand the principle of `AttributeProvider`?)

Comment: Hello, your thinking is very ingenious.  I found a thread on the platform, hope it can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59080470/c-sharp-interface-implementation-with-an-interface-property

Answer (score 0):

Okay, It seems like I had a wrong interpretation about what `AttributeProvider` is doing:

`AttributeProvider`s description is `Enables Attribute Redirection` - but this doesn't mean, that it will (in my example) attach the Attributes of `IPermissionBasedControl.PermissionKey` to `ExtendedTextBox.PermissionKey`, the `AttributeProvider` is having effect on the Attributes of the type of the property.

i.e.: If I would specify

```
    [AttributeProvider(typeof(Color))]
    public object PermissionKey { get; set; }
```

the VisualStudio Designer would now Apply the Attributes of `Color` to the Value-Field for picking the object. (And therefore show a color-picker)

So, technically spoken, the `AttributeProvider` redirects Attributes for the type of the property, not for the property itself.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. After reading your answer, it's like clearing away the clouds and mist. You can mark this as an answer to help more people.